# #react-native [0.42] - New Navigation with Redux - Cannot map state to props

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-navigation

RN: 0.42

1. I tried to use the new navigation (that was released) + redux and I am unable to map the initial state of the redux to props, in a screen where the store is passed.
2. I followed this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/guides/redux
3. I have written my custom reducer.

```js
export const types = {
  ...
}

export const actionCreators = {
  authenticate: () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    ...
  }
}

const initialState = {
  auth: {
    ...
  }
}

export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const {auth} = state
  const {type, payload, error} = action

  switch (type) {
    ...
  }

  return state
}
```

4. In index.ios.js I have combined my own custom reducer

```js
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';
import * from 'appReducer';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: MyTabNavigator },
});

const navReducer = (state, action) => {
  const newState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
  return (newState ? newState : state)
};

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  nav: navReducer,
  app: appReducer
});

@connect(state => ({
  nav: state.nav,
}))
class AppWithNavigationState extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
        dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
        state: this.props.nav,
      })} />
    );
  }
}

const store = createStore(appReducer);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppWithNavigationState />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

5. Inside Home.js, 'mapStateToProps' does not work.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { actionCreators } from './appRedux'

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  //This is the problem: Here 'state' has no 'auth' object attached to it
  auth: state.auth
})

class Home extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    const {dispatch} = this.props
    //Dispatch works
    dispatch(actionCreators.authenticate('testId', 'testToken'))
  }

  
  render() {
    const {auth} = this.props

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>
            Welcome {auth['name']}
          </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  }
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)
```

6. Note, the dispatch function is available to fire but the 'state' does not have the reducer 'initialState' attached to it.

Please let me know the correct way to attach the reducer initialState to various Screens in the new RN navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it where you are doing wrong, in your  index.ios.js change `import * from 'appReducer';` to `import {reducer} from 'appReducer';` then your current combined reducer function will be like

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  nav: navReducer,
  app: reducer
});
```

then in your home.js your mapStateToProps should be like

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  //This is the problem: Here 'state' has no 'auth' object attached to it
  authState: state.app    //remember store only contains reducers as state that you had passed in combineReducer function
})
```

now use it in your component like

```
this.props.authState.auth        //remember you had wrapped your auth object within initialState object
```